# How do I remove bathtub drain screw?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I currently have a toe touch drain stopper installed (see first photo), and would like to replace it with a twist stopper (see second photo).

The screw on the bottom of the toe touch stopper is stuck in the drain, and I'm assuming it's supposed to come out with the stopper.

Any idea how to remove the screw and install the new twist stopper?

[image: toe touch and drain with screw]

[image: new twist stopper]

Comment: you could remove the drain to do it. Your new stopper might not fit it as that screw thread is not a standard size (they come in lots of sizes) - I think the lower one the nut retains it , see if it will thread on to that screw. There is no 'magic' easy way to do this other than removing the drain - there are tools to do that too.

Answer (score 1):

I use large needle nose pliers if I don't have a drain wrench. The pliers need to be opened and in contact withthe outside edge of the metal cross member. Turn counter /anti clockwise. These parts are usually brass and or plastic so they don't usually rust. If the assembly starts deforming with needle nose a drain wrench will be needed drain wrenches slip over all 4 points and provide more force without damaging the existing flange. [Here is an example](https://www.greydock.com/smart-dumbell-tub-drain-removal-tool.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&adpos=1o5&scid=scplp28265&sc_intid=28265&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI_NGitqKy2QIV1o1-Ch07QA-GEAQYBSABEgK1PvD_BwE) One of the less expensive ones I saw with a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ton of rust release penetration spray and a pair of long nose vice grip pliers to lock onto the bolt. Then use long straight jaw pliers (10" or 12" - the bigger the better) to turn the vice grips.

There is no guarantee this will work because the bolt is very small and it's difficult to get a good grip on. Might be better to just replace the drain. In that case use straight long nose pliers, open them wide and jam them in the drain, then use long straight jaw pliers to grab onto them and turn them.

In any case you want a large lever to give you leverage.